# How to zoom out container, after Leaflet reached minZoom?

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, html

On one of our main pages, Leaflet map occupies 90% of the page with only the top nav (position: fixed;)

But on touch devices, user can accidentally zoom-in not on a map, but on the entire page. If they do - there is no way for them to un-zoom to see the top nav, because any touch action would zoom-in-out the map.

Ideally, I'm trying to find solution so that the page would zoom-out, after Leaflet reaches minZoom level. Any other ideas are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to completely disable page zoom, using [`meta` tag `viewport` attribute `content="user-scalable=no"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done.

Leaflet relies on the [`touch-action` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) to prevent the browser from pinch-zooming the whole page.

Note how there is no value for that property that allows to pinch-zoom *only out*. Leaflet can only enable/disable pinch-zooming as a whole.

You could disable the [`touchZoom` handler of the map](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-touchzoom) by running something like `map.touchZoom.disable()`, or `map.on('zoomend', function(){ if (map.getZoom()===map.options.minZoom) map.touchZoom.disable() })` but that will disable *all* pinch-zooming in Leaflet, and enable *all* pinch-zooming of the whole page.